# Started or felt palpitation

Tags: word-usage

Which is the correct way to mention the idea of sudden feeling of heart palpitation:

> *My heart started palpitating.*
>   or
>   *I felt my heart <strike>is</strike> palpitating.*

I was just describing the journey to a haunted house. So I had to choose any one of the above two sentences. The complete description that I used is as follows:

> We reached late in the evening in the mall. When we reached a shopping store, we just noticed that there was a scary house near that shop. There was a good discount on the tickets of scary house. Thus, I purchased 2 tickets and then I entered the house along with my wife. There they have played loud scary music. **Suddenly my heart started palpitating.**

So, I know what the word means. I just need to know how to use it so it sounds natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say:

> There they *were playing* loud scary music. Suddenly my heart started **pounding**.

though using it in the present tense is more common.

See [*pound*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pound):

> 8. *verb*
>      If your heart is pounding, it is beating with an unusually strong and fast rhythm, usually because you are afraid.
>      *I'm sweating, my heart is pounding. I can't breathe.*

I would say *palpitation* is more commonly used in medical contexts.

Answer (score -1):

An elegant way to express the idea could be

> I wondered whether my wife could hear my palpitating heart.

That way you use the word, and it does not seem awkward; rather in context.

Comment: This doesn't match in meaning the examples that the question has, which don't mention the idea of anyone hearing. Your suggestion doesn't suggest a sudden onset of palpitations.

Comment: Probably not, considering the "loud scary music".